# Range filters - accept each date

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using range filters in elasticsearch with different options like

```
"date" : { "gte" : "now-1d" }
"date" : { "gte" : "now-1y" }
```

(it depends on the value of an variable)

Is it possible to define a keyword to accept all kinds of date, even if there is no field date?

Maybe something like:

```
"date" : { "gte" : _all }
```

Comment: If you want to get any date, maybe you should remove the range filter...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "exists"?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html
You should be able to combine two filters with bool - should /should not and filter on date gte nnnn OR not exists field: date
(I'm assuming you want to filter on date range if you have a date, and include results where the date is missing as well)